# When is the Fourier transform of a periodic discrete signal $\mathcal{F}x[k]$ the same as $x[k]$ up to a diagonal matrix

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, fourier-transform, eigendecomposition

I am looking for all pairs $(x[n],q)$ where $x[n]$ is a  periodic discrete signal with period $N$ and $q$ is a rational number satisfying the following identity:
$$\mathcal{F}x[k]=e^{i(q-\frac{\pi k}{N})}x[k]$$
where $k=0,1,\cdots, N-1$.

Comment: The query in the _title_ of your question is different from the statement in the _text_ of your question.  In the _title_, an arbitrary diagonal matrix is under consideration, but in the text, the diagonal matrix is required to be of a very particular form.  Which is it?

Comment: I'll go with "the text is always a clarification for the title", so the text version would be definite (also, I'll take the more constrained problem over the general one)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Actually, the more general problem is easier and there are plenty of solutions. The specific one might not have any solutions at all....

Answer (score 1):

Let $\newcommand{\F}{\mathbf{F}_{{}_N}} \F$ be the (unitary) DFT-Matrix of size $N$. Let $\newcommand{\x}{\mathbf x}\x$ be the vector $\x=(x[0],\ldots x[N-1])$. Your equation says:

\begin{align}\DeclareMathOperator{\diag}{diag}\newcommand{\tildF}{\tilde{\mathbf{F}}_{{}_N}}\newcommand{\D}{\mathbf D_{{}_N}}
\F \x &= \diag\left(e^{i\left(q-\frac{\pi k}N\right)}\right)_{k=0,\ldots,N-1} \x\\
&=e^{iq}\diag\left(e^{-i\frac{\pi k}N}\right)_{k=0,\ldots,N-1}\x\\
\F\underbrace{\diag\left(e^{i\frac{\pi k}N}\right)_{k=0,\ldots,N-1}}_{=:\D}\x&=e^{iq}\x\\
\underbrace{\F\D}_{=:\tildF}\,\x&=e^{iq}\x\\
\tag{1}\label{evprob}
\tildF\x&=e^{iq}\x
\end{align}
so you're looking for eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $\tildF$ (it's a given that all EV take the shape $e^{ir},r\in\mathbb R$, since $\|\tildF\|\equiv1$)!

Since that involves a DFT matrix, it's not trivial, but

> B. Dickinson and K. Steiglitz, "Eigenvectors and functions of the discrete Fourier transform," in *IEEE Transactions on Acoustics, Speech, and Signal Processing*, vol. 30, no. 1, pp. 25-31, February 1982, doi: 10.1109/TASSP.1982.1163843. [Link](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/%7Eken/Eigenvectors82.pdf).

shows us an approach.

Note that if I'm not mistaken, then $\F\D$ is a kind of a cyclic shift of $\F$, so that the eigenvalues might simply be the same.

Comment: Thanks for your  attention.  All that you explained are completely right except the diagonal matrix $D_N$ that you defined. The entries are all in the unit circle but not absolutely 1,-1.

Comment: @ABB ah darn, forgot the $/N$ there. Let me fix that!

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dnr version:** *No* nonzero vector can satisfy the requirement stated in the *body* of this question.

The rest of this answer is a long-winded proof of the assertion above.

The Discrete Fourier Transform of the column vector $\mathbf x = \big[x[0], x[1], \ldots, x[N-1]\big]^T$ is defined as the column vector $\mathbf X = \big[X[0], X[1], \ldots, X[N-1]\big]^T$ where
$$X[k] = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n]\exp\left(-j\frac{2\pi kn}N\right).\tag{1}$$
Thus, $\mathbf X = \mathbf{Fx}$ where $\mathbf F$ is the $N\times N$ DFT matrix (with rows and columns numbered from $0$ to $N-1$) with entries given by $\mathbf F_{k,n}=\exp\left(-j\frac{2\pi kn}N\right)$. It is well-known that $\mathbf F$ is a symmetric matrix and enjoys the property that for $1 \leq k \leq N-1$, the $k$-th row of $\mathbf F$ is the complex conjugate of the $(N-k)$-th row.  Furthermore, the inverse of $\mathbf F$ is $N^{-1}\mathbf F^*$ where $\mathbf F^*$ is the $N\times N$ matrix with entries
$\mathbf F^*_{k,n}=\exp\left(j\frac{2\pi kn}N\right) = \left(\mathbf F_{k,n}\right)^*$. Thus, the set of rows of $\mathbf F^*$ is the same as the set of rows of $\mathbf F$, but the rows occur in reverse order from Row $1$ through Row $N-1$ in the two matrices. All this is a verbose way of saying that
$$x[k] = \frac 1N\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} X[n]\exp\left(j\frac{2\pi kn}N\right)\tag{2}$$
or $\mathbf x$ is the *inverse* DFT of $\mathbf X$. Finally, note that the $(k,n)$-th element of $\mathbf F^2$ is
\begin{align}
\mathbf F_{k,n}^2 &= \sum_{m=0}^{N-1}\mathbf F_{k,m}\mathbf F_{m,n}\\
&= \sum_{m=0}^{N-1}\exp\left(-j\frac{2\pi km}N\right)\exp\left(-j\frac{2\pi mn}N\right)\\
&= \sum_{m=0}^{N-1}\exp\left(-j\frac{2\pi m(n+k)}N\right)\\
&= \begin{cases}N, & n+k \equiv 0\bmod N, \\
0, &\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}
\end{align}
Thus,
$$\mathbf F_{0,0}^2= \mathbf F_{1,N-1}^2= z\mathbf F_{2,N-2}^2 = \cdots = \mathbf F_{N-1,1}^2 = N \tag{3}$$
and all other entries in $\mathbf F^2$ are $0$.

---

The query in the *title* of this question asks "When does $\mathbf X$ equal $\operatorname{diag}[d_0, d_1, \ldots, d_{N-1}]\mathbf x$?" has the trivial answer "Whenever *no* entry of $\mathbf x$ is $0$.";  all we need to do is set $d_k = \dfrac{X[k]}{(x[k])}$ for $0 \leq k \leq N-1$ where we know the the fraction is properly defined since we are guaranteed that $x[k]\neq 0$ for any $k$.

The query in the *body* of this question is considerably more restricted and possibly has no solution at all.  It asks "When does $X[k]$ equal
$\exp\left(j \left(q - \frac{\pi k}N\right)\right)x[k]$ for all $k$, $0 \leq k \leq N-1$, where $q$ is some fixed rational number?" Equivalently, we want to find all $\mathbf x$ such that
\begin{align}
\mathbf X &= \exp(-jq) \operatorname{diag}\left[1, \exp\left(-j\frac{2\pi}N\right), \exp\left(-j\frac{2\pi 2}N\right), \cdots, \exp\left(-j\frac{2\pi(N-1)}N\right)\right]\mathbf x \tag{3}\\
\mathbf X &= \exp(-jq)\hat{\mathbf x} \tag{4}
\end{align}
where $\hat{\mathbf x}$ is the vector with $n$-th element $\displaystyle\hat{x}[n] = \exp\left(-j\frac{2\pi n}N\right) x[n]$.

For an *arbitrary* vector $\mathbf x$ (that is, not necessarily a solution to $(3)$ or $(4)$), what is the DFT $\hat{\mathbf X}$ of $\hat{\mathbf x}$?  Well, from $(1)$, we have that
\begin{align}
\hat{X}[k] &= \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \hat{x}[n]\exp\left(-j\frac{2\pi kn}N\right)\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \exp\left(-j\frac{2\pi n}N\right){x}[n]\exp\left(-j\frac{2\pi kn}N\right)\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} {x}[n]\exp\left(-j\frac{2\pi (k+1)n}N\right)\\
&= X[k+1 \bmod N].
\end{align}
Thus,
$$\hat{\mathbf X} = \big[\hat X[0], \hat X[1], \ldots, \hat X[N-1]\big]^T = \big[X[1], X[2], \ldots, X[N-1], X[0]\big]^T$$
which is the cyclic shift referred to in Marcus Müller's answer.

And now, let us resume the assumption that $\mathbf x$ is an alleged solution to $(3)$ and $(4)$.  Remembering that $\exp(-jq)$ is a scalar, we have that
\begin{align}
\mathbf X &= \exp(-jq)\hat{\mathbf x}\\
\mathbf{Fx}&= \exp(-jq)\hat{\mathbf x}\\
\mathbf{F}^2\mathbf x &= \exp(-jq)\mathbf{F}\hat{\mathbf x}\\
\mathbf{F}^2\mathbf x &= \exp(-jq)\hat{\mathbf X}.
\end{align}
But,
$$\mathbf{F}^2\mathbf x = N\big[x[0], x[N-1], x[N-2], \cdots ,  x[1]\big]^T\tag{5}$$ while
\begin{align}\exp(-jq)\hat{\mathbf X} &= \exp(-jq)\big[\hat X[0], \hat X[1], \ldots, \hat X[N-1]\big]^T\\
&= \exp(-jq)\big[X[1], X[2], \ldots, X[N-1], X[0]\big]^T. \tag{6}
\end{align}
Two takeaways from the fact that the vectors on the right sides of Eqs. $(5)$ and $(6)$ are equal are
\begin{align}x[0]&= N^{-1}\exp(-jq)X[1]\tag{7}\\x[1] &= N^{-1}\exp(-jq)X[0]\tag{8}.
\end{align}
On the other hand, Eqs. $(3)$ and $(4)$ assure us that
\begin{align}x[0]&=\exp(jq)X[0]\tag{9}\\x[1] &= \exp(jq)\exp\left(j\frac{\pi}{N}\right)X[1]\tag{10}.
\end{align}
Now, Eqs. $(7)$and $(9)$ tell us that
$$X[1] = N\exp(2jq)X[0]\tag{11}$$ while Eqs. $(8)$and $(10)$ lead to
$$X[1] = \frac 1N \exp(-2jq)\exp\left(-j\frac{\pi}{N}\right)X[0]\tag{12}$$
which are contradictory results unless $X[0]=X[1]=0$. Similar arguments can be used to express $X[k+1]$ in terms of $X[k]$ in contradictory ways, leading to the conclusion that the only $\mathbf x$ that can satisfy $(3)$ and $(4)$ is $\mathbf 0$.

The conclusion is that *no* nonzero vector $\mathbf x$ can satisfy the desired requirement $(3)$.